# Mapping SNP coordinates to gene coordinates is too slow

Tags: perl, optimization, match

I have two tab-delimited files like these

**File 1** (these are *Single Nucleotide Polymorphism* (SNP) positions)

```
Chr1 26690
Chr1 33667
Chr1 75049
.
.

Chr2 12342
Chr2 32642
Chr2 424421
.
.
```

**File 2** (these are gene start and end coordinates)

```
Chr1    2903    10817   LOC_Os01g01010
Chr1    2984    10562   LOC_Os01g01010
Chr1    11218   12435   LOC_Os01g01019
Chr1    12648   15915   LOC_Os01g01030
Chr1    16292   18304   LOC_Os01g01040
Chr1    16292   20323   LOC_Os01g01040
Chr1    16321   20323   LOC_Os01g01040
Chr1    16321   20323   LOC_Os01g01040
Chr1    22841   26971   LOC_Os01g01050
Chr1    22841   26971   LOC_Os01g01050
.
.
```

What I want is to match SNPs in file 1 to genes in file 2. The script should match the string in the first column of the files, and if they match it should then find which gene in the file 2 contains the corresponding SNP and return the locus ID from the fourth column of File 2.

Here's the script I have written

```
use strict;

my $i1 = $ARGV[0];            # SNP 
my $i2 = $ARGV[1];            # gene coordinate

open(I1, $i1);
open(I2, $i2);

my @snp  = ();
my @coor = ();

while( <I1> ) {
  push(@snp, $_);    
}

while ( <I2> ) {
  push(@coor, $_);   
}

for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#snp; $i++ ) {

    my @snp_line = split "\t", $snp[$i];

    for ( my $j = 0; $j <= $#coor; $j++ ) {

        my @coor_line = split "\t", $coor[$i];   

        if ( $snp_line[0] eq $coor_line[0] ) {

            if ( $snp_line[1] >= $coor_line[1] && $snp_line[1] <= $coor_line[2] ) {
              print "$snp_line[0]\t$snp_line[1]\t$coor_line[3]\n";
              goto a;
            }
        }   
    }
a: 
}
```

The problem is that obviously this is not the best way to do it as it iterates over all the ~60,000 lines in file 2 for each SNP in line 1. Also, it ran overnight and did not go past `Chr1`; we have upto `Chr12`.

Comment: You have not asked a question. What do you need help with? Is something not working?

Comment: sorry, made edits

Comment: Not related to the problem: There is a `goto` in your code. Please don't do that. Ever. You want `last` to break out of the loop. For several loops, put a label before the outer loop: `OUTER: for () { for () { last OUTER } }`.

Comment: How many lines do the files each have? How much memory does your computer have? It might be better to process the SNP file line by line.

Comment: The SNP file had ~50000 lines and the gene coordinate file has about ~66000. Memory is not an issue

Comment: You want to find a single match? Nothing else?

Comment: Ya just the match. Possible that one gene can have multiple SNPs. I found the bug in the script earlier. Sorry for all the trouble. But if you have a better option, happy to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @user2888306: `while ( <I1> ) { push @snp, $_; }` is usually written `@snp = <I1>`

Comment: @user2888306: `for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#snp; $i++ ) { ... }` is usually written `for my $i ( 0 .. $#snp ) { ... }`

Comment: @user2888306: You should avoid using HTML markup (such as `<br>`) in your posts. Stack Overflow uses [*John Gruber's* ***Markdown*** system](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) which is very much easier to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could work with these files when reformatted as UCSC BED format, using a toolkit like [BEDOPS](https://github.com/bedops/bedops) that does efficient set operations on sorted BED files.

Convert your first file of SNPs to a sorted BED file:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '{ print $1, $2, ($2+1); }' snps.txt | sort-bed - > snps.bed
```

Sort the genes ("file 2"):

```
$ sort-bed genes.unsorted.txt > genes.bed
```

Map SNPs to genes:

```
$ bedmap --echo --echo-map-id-uniq --delim '\t' snps.bed genes.bed > answer.bed
```

If you need to, you can strip the end position of the SNP from the answer:

```
$ cut -f1,2,4 answer.bed > answer.txt
```

These tools will run very fast, usually within a few moments.

I would not use Perl or Python to do these kinds of set operations, unless I was doing some kind of academic exercise.

Comment: Much faster. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working script, the one posted above had bugs

```
use strict;

my $i1=$ARGV[0];            # SNP 
my $i2=$ARGV[1];            # gene coordinate

open(I1,$i1);
open(I2,$i2);

my @snp=();
my @coor=();

while(<I1>)
{
push(@snp,$_);  
}
while(<I2>)
{
push(@coor,$_); 
}

for(my $i=0;$i<=$#snp;$i++)
{
my @snp_line = split "\t",$snp[$i];

for(my $j=0;$j<=$#coor;$j++)
{
    my @coor_line = split "\t",$coor[$j];

    if ($snp_line[0] eq $coor_line[0])
    {   
        if ($snp_line[1] >= $coor_line[1] && $snp_line[1] <= $coor_line[2])
        {
            print "$snp_line[0]\t$snp_line[1]\t$coor_line[3]\n";                
        }

    }   

}

}
```

This one does the job.